# How to get data from properties object

Tags: java

I have an Properties object like below

```
Properties props=new Properties();
```

i added list data to propertie object like below

```
props.put(List<String>,List<String>)
```

then how can i retrive the Key from properties object

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following

```
for(String key : keys){
    // Do something with the property.
    props.getProperty(key);
}
```

Comment: I assume you provided the keys in your `props.put(List<String>,List<String>)`, right?

Comment: Ok.. let's say you have a bunch of `props.put(key , value)` lines.. and you get the `key` from a `List`, the this is the `keys` I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Properties class extends `Hashtable` so you can get all the keys with `keySet()`

```
for(Object key: props.keySet()) {
    // Do whatever you want with the key
}
```

That said I would strongly suggest to revisit your use case and use a `HashMap` or `Hashtable` if non-string keys are a norm. Properties abstraction is designed to work well with keys that are either strings or have meaningful string representations.

Comment: I have data like props.put(List<String>,List<String>).but i tried what you said i didn't get all the values.i am getting only last value

Comment: If the first value you pass in is the same every time, then it's expected: All keys in a Hashtable must be unique. What are you tring to do? Maybe an ArrayList or some other java collection is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You want the [stringPropertyNames()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#stringPropertyNames%28%29) method of your `Properties` object.

```
for (String key : props.stringPropertyNames) {
    // Process the key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For String-based properties, here's an example which iterates through the property names, returning the corresponding value for each:

```
for (String key : props.stringPropertyNames()) {
    String val = props.getProperty(key);
    System.out.println("property \"" + key + "\" has value \"" + val + "\".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the file, after generating it? Does it look as expected?

I guess not:

Docu says:
`public V put(K key, V value)` - it does not say `public List<V> put(List<K> keys, List<V> values)`

(Assuming, `props.put(List<String>,List<String>)` means, you are trying to store multiple key/value pairs at once)